# CodeIgniter On LAMP not loading database library

Tags: php

I have installed `LAMP` TURNKEY Debianf Wheezy

I unzipped codeigniter into `/var/www/`

It worked fine.

But If I `autoload` or `load` any controller that uses library `database` it throws a `500` error.

The database credentials are working fine.

Checked with another script involving database connectivity.

Other `libraries` can be loaded with no problem ( for ex. session)

Its showing me a `500` error if i load the database library . Please help !

Comment: download a fresh version of codeigniter 3 then give it another try